# How to fix Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

Apex class :

```
 public static List<AggregateResult>  calculOppN1(String userId, List<Id> filialeIds, List<Id> marketIds , Integer count , Date startDateN1 , Date  endDateN1){

        String codeGie;
        Id accId;
        String queryOppN1;
        Id Devis = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Devis').getRecordTypeId();
        List<User> lstUser = getInfosCommCourtier(userId);
        Integer currentDayOfMonth = Date.today().day();
        if(!lstUser.isEmpty()){
            codeGie = lstUser[0].TECH_CodeGie__c;
            accId = lstUser[0].AccountId;
        }
        queryOppN1 = 'SELECT count(Id)  cnt ' 
        + 'FROM Opportunity '
        + 'WHERE AccountId =: accId '
        + 'AND PrmCreatedDate__c >= :startDateN1 AND PrmCreatedDate__c <= :endDateN1  AND RecordTypeId =: Devis ';
         queryOppN1 += (filialeIds.size() > 0) ? 'AND SubsidiaryId__c IN :filialeIds ' : ' ';
        queryOppN1 += (marketIds.size() > 0) ? 'AND MarketId__c IN :marketIds ' : ' ';
        queryOppN1 += 'AND IsDeleted = false  GROUP BY Name';


        List<AggregateResult>  countResult =  Database.query(queryOppN1) ;

        return countResult ;
    }
```

the calculOppN1 method is called in this method :

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Integer  getInfosOppN1(String userId, List<Id> filialeIds, List<Id> marketIds , Integer count ) {
    Date  startDateN1;
    Date endDateN1 ;
    Integer currentDayOfMonth = Date.today().day();
    Integer finalCount = 0 ;
    Integer tempCount =0;
    Integer days ;
    List<AggregateResult> results = new List<AggregateResult>();
    for(Integer i=1 ; i<=count ; i ++){
        tempCount = 0 ;
        startDateN1 = Date.newInstance(System.today().year() - 1 , i, 1);
        if(i==count){
            endDateN1 = Date.newInstance(System.today().year() - 1 , i,currentDayOfMonth);
        }else{

            if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 ||i == 7 ||i == 8 ||i == 10 || i == 12 ){
                days = 31 ;
            }else if(i == 4 ||i == 6 ||i == 9 ||i == 11 ){
                days = 30 ;
            }else if(i == 2){
                days = 28 ;
            }
            endDateN1 = Date.newInstance(System.today().year() - 1 , i,days);
        }
       results= calculOppN1(userId , filialeIds , marketIds , i , startDateN1 , endDateN1  );

 
       tempCount = results.size() ;
        finalCount  += tempCount;
    }

    return finalCount ;
}
```

the goal of the method getInfosOppN1 is to return number of opportunity for the last year *( from 1 Janu 2022 until 2 Nov 2022 )*  its throws an error because total number if greater than +50K

I was thinking to get the number of opportunity by month means ( January2022 , Feb2022 .. Novebre2022) and then sum it  or using Batch like :
Batch class:

```
   public class Batch_CalculOppN1 implements  Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.stateful  {


    private List<AggregateResult> results = new List<AggregateResult>();

    private String userId;
    private List<Id> filialeIds;
    private List<Id> marketIds;
    private Date startDateN1;
    private Date endDateN1;
    private Integer count;

    global Batch_CalculOppN1(String userId, List<Id> filialeIds, List<Id> marketIds,Integer count, Date startDateN1, Date endDateN1) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.filialeIds = filialeIds;
        this.marketIds = marketIds;
        this.startDateN1 = startDateN1;
        this.endDateN1 = endDateN1;
        this.count = count;
    }

      public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         String codeGie;
        Id accId;
        String queryOppN1;
        Id Devis = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Devis').getRecordTypeId();
        List<User> lstUser = DAS_ListController.getInfosCommCourtier(userId);
        Integer currentDayOfMonth = Date.today().day();
        if(!lstUser.isEmpty()){
            codeGie = lstUser[0].TECH_CodeGie__c;
            accId = lstUser[0].AccountId;
        }
        queryOppN1 = 'SELECT count(Id)  cnt ' 
        + 'FROM Opportunity '
        + 'WHERE AccountId =: accId '
        + 'AND PrmCreatedDate__c >= :startDateN1 AND PrmCreatedDate__c <= :endDateN1  AND RecordTypeId =: Devis ';
        queryOppN1 += (filialeIds.size() > 0) ? 'AND SubsidiaryId__c IN :filialeIds ' : ' ';
        queryOppN1 += (marketIds.size() > 0) ? 'AND MarketId__c IN :marketIds ' : ' ';
        queryOppN1 += 'AND IsDeleted = false  GROUP BY Name';
                return Database.getQueryLocator(queryOppN1);

    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
     for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT COUNT(Id) cnt FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :scope]) {
            results.add(ar);
        }
    }
 public List<AggregateResult> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

I call my batch in getInfosOppN1 method like :

```
    List<AggregateResult> results = new List<AggregateResult>();
   Batch_CalculOppN1 batchClass = new Batch_CalculOppN1(userId, filialeIds, marketIds,i, startDateN1, endDateN1);
           Database.executeBatch(batchClass, 200); 
           results = batchClass.getResults();
```

following @Renato answer i shouldn't call   `.getResults()` right after `.executeBatch` How can i refactor this in order to get (+60K) records from the batch ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you misunderstand how a batch class works. The batchable interface is used for tasks that should be performed asynchronously and when the system has enough computing resources to do it.

With the above into consideration, you need to understand that, while possible to get results from a specific method in your batch class in the same transaction, it is not what the batch class is for. Calling `.getResults()` right after `.executeBatch` means that you are using the same synchronous transaction to do so - which means that the synchronous transaction governor limits still apply, which results in your error message.

In short: you cannot fetch the results of your batch in the same transaction. You can still process your 60k+ records, sure, if you do it asynchronously. And whatever you need to do, needs to be done in batches of 200 records (as specified in your snippet, which is also the default value, so you don't really need that argument) within the `execute` method of your batch class.

If you need to show this record information, I would advise against using Apex and using a report instead.

Also: your class methods do not need to be `global`. They should be `public` instead.

---

Edit based on OP's comments:

Given that you want to ***count*** the number of opportunities and your method returns an integer value, you should be either using a report or have your query return an aggregation **that is not grouped by the opportunity's name**. As it is, the current aggregation is equivalent of saying "list and count all opportunities with the same name" which would yield a list of opportunities with the aggregate value set to 1 or more (pretty much equal to the number of opportunities depending on how you name them in your business process).

Use `SELECT COUNT() FROM Opportunity WHERE <conditions>` instead of grouping. This will return an Integer that you can use in the rest of your process. Bear in mind that this might still give you some headache due to the governor limits depending on how you formulate the WHERE clause. In that case, have your org [explain the query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84311/how-do-i-see-query-plan-explain-data-for-a-given-soql-query) for you so you can fix it, or try a different approach.

Comment: How can i process my 60K reocrds? it throws an error because the query on the start method is returning + 50K records - i want to get the result of my soql in another class to do other manipulations ..do you have any approach ?

Comment: Depends on what you consider "process". Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish with the queried records.

Comment: i clarified my question , question edited ( hope its clear)

Comment: I added more info to my comment based on your changes.

Comment: i should execute the query in rest API

Comment: I don't see how executing this through the console, the CLI or the API would be any different.

Comment: How ? do you have an example? why ? Any suggestions?

Comment: I gave you the answer in my last post. You shouldn't group the results by name. Then your query will work.

Comment: why not? when i delete *Group by name* there's no issue but returning number of records is wrong , it shows 11 instead of 61k

Comment: I also explained why not in my answer. If you want the total count you don't need to group. Also it doesn't make sense for it to return just 11 when your query grouped by the name returns many more records. You might want to recheck your code with a simple WHERE clause and add more restrictions to see what is capping your result there.

Comment: i agree its strange .. but the solution isn't to delete "Group by name" , i need to execute the soql in rest API

Comment: The real solution is for you to properly explain what you are expected to get from that aggregation. As it is, you are only getting a list of aggregated results by opportunity name. Is this right? You have 60k+ opportunity names in your org? If that's the case, then you should look at using this batch to offload the aggregated data to a separate record and then query that instead (not in a single transaction, of course, because that is not possible in this scenario).

Comment: my question is very clear , my soql returning +60K records - i'm blocked on how to refactor it or how to get the result of the batch i mentioned . .

Comment: You can't get the result in a single transaction. It is this simple. Your method returns a single integer after summing the values for your opportunities. You should probably have a batch doing this sum and then storing it elsewhere.

Comment: elsewhere? like?

Comment: Like in a separate object.

Comment: I don't think so. I already explained what you should be doing to solve your issue with the information you provided. You can very easily search this side and the web, in general, to get a sense of what you should be doing. Wish you the best of luck trying to sort this out.